# Trying to determine which distribution to use for my percentage data for mixed effects model

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model, skewness, beta-distribution, percentage

I am seeing a lot of different answers to percentage data, either beta or binomial with a logit link and not to use poison distribution because it isn't count data. My response variable is retention efficiency for different food types ((Incurrent food - excurrent food)/ incurrent food) *100. There are 5 different food types. I am looking to see if the sponges from different regions and genus differ in their consumption of the five food types. I am attaching a histogram of the data which has more values closer to 1 or 100% retention (none are actually 100%). I am wondering what distribution would be best at fitting my data which would be continuous proportion I think but the data is obviously not normal. I will probably be doing some sort of generalized linear mixed-effects model

[image]

Comment: Do you have values that are 100% and 0%? Or are all observations between those two numbers?

Comment: all are between 0 and 100, no 0% or 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use beta regression with the logit link function. I would take your data, which is in percent, and then divide by 100 to get it to proportions and between the 0 and 1 range that standard beta regression expects.

From your histogram, it looks like you're using R. The `{brms}` package supports mixed models with beta regression, using the `family = Beta()` argument. The link function for the expected value is logit and for the dispersion parameter is log, by default.

The `{gamlss}` package also implements this, but they employ a less common reparameterization of the beta distribution.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that package

Comment: Great! Glad to help. If that answers your question, feel free to mark it as answered to close the question out and help others. Thanks!